# What does it mean to "re-tank" toilet?

Tags: leak, toilet

My contractor included "re-tank" toilet in work that he said he had completed in a list of works to be carried out, but we are still having leaking. What does re-tank mean and how do I know that its been done. I think maybe it hasn't!

Comment: If the job included 'fix the leaking toilet' and it's still leaking, then I don't think you care what exactly he did - he needs to come back and fix it!

Answer (score 1):

I would take it to mean that he either installed a new tank on the toilet bowl, or re-installed the existing tank.

This might be done:

- If the tank was damaged in some way.
- If the tank was leaking at the tank-bowl union.
- To change the look of the toilet, without replacing the entire unit.

[image: Toilet]

It could also mean that he installed a new flush, and/or fill valve assembly.

This might be done:

- If the toilet was leaking.
- If the toilet was running intermittently.
- If the toilet was not flushing properly.

[image: Fill and Flush Valve Assemblies]
<sup>***NOTE:*** There are various types of fill and flush valve assemblies, these are simply two of the more common types.</sup>